# How to disable one assetic filter in Symfony 2.3?

Tags: php, symfony-2.3, assetic

i'm use a bundle with a `{% stylesheets filters="?yui_css" %}` twig tag in template.
How can i disable only this filter globally in my application for all of enveroments?

Of course, I could to rewrite a twig template in this bundle, but it's installed as a vendor by composer, and i don't want to modify the vendor bundle.

Symfony 2.3 is used.

I need something like this in config.yml:

```
assetic:
    filters:
        yui_css:
            disabled: true
```

Comment: I can't use Java on my server and with this filter (without Java) "assetic:dump --no-debug" fails with error. Because i have to disable it.